# Laravel - Eager loading from model relationship

Tags: php, laravel

On my page, I have the following pagination query:

```
$followingUsers = $user->followerUsers()->paginate(80);
```

In the blade template, I @foreach $followingUsers as $follower

In this foreach loop, there is the following check:

```
@if (Auth::user()->isFollowed($follower))
```

This is referencing
I'm using the Laravel N+1 detector, and this is telling me that this I should do the following:

> You should add "with('App\Follower')" to eager-load this relation.

Which of course won't work, I can't just write something like:

$followingUsers = $user->followerUsers()->with('App\Follower')->paginate(80);

This will of course cause an error.

So how do I write this eager load? Something like...

```
$followingUsers = $user->followerUsers()->with(Auth::user()->isFollowed($follower))->paginate(80);
```

or something. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `isFollowed` a relationship on the `$follower` model to fetch how many followers that model has, so what the detector is telling you to do is load the relationship that is used by that method on the `$followingUsers` collection:

```php
// I'm guessing the name of the relationship that is called.
$followingUsers = $user->followerUsers()->with('followers')->paginate(80);
```

That would fix your error however it is not the most ideal solution because presumably your users could all have a lot of followers so you are loading all followers for the 80 users in memory just to see if they include the authenticated user.
A more efficient approach would be to load the authenticated user's followers and use that in the `isFollowed`. Then you don't need to load anything because the authenticated user stays the same and Laravel can store the results of the relationship for subsequent calls.

Comment: Good point! I've actually done something similar before so I'm surprised I didn't think of it. Thanks!